# how to join channels with a variable username (mirc)

Tags: code-snippets, irc, mirc

simple question, i guess, but I'm fairly new to this, so maybe you can help me.
I made a bot for a chat, which i want to share with people.
So, my first thought was: i'll add a command (!join), which then will let the bot
join the specific channel. For some reason (i guess its due the operators), my join won't work.

Here is the snippet:

```
on *:TEXT:!join:#: {
  var %name = $nick
  ;/msg $chan joining channel %name 
  /join #%nick
}
```

But it just won't connect. Any ideas?

If i just use /kick $nick (or %name), it works, so i guess this # is messing things up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you dont need to use / on event commands, since everything will be interpreted as command inside events, by the way, since %name = $nick you can use $+($chr(35),$nick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/join $chr(35) $+ %nick
```

Explanation:  A variable name must be a word on its own in your line of code for it to be recognised as a variable name. Therefore, `#%nick` will be interpreted as the string `#%nick`, whereas `%nick` will be interpreted as the name of the user issuing the command.

To append the value of a variable or identifier, you can use the identifier `$+` which appends strings together. For instance, `a $+ b` will return `ab`.

Another issue arises when you use `# $+ %nick`, because `#` is an alias for the identifier `$chan`. This means that if I were to type !join in `#test`, it would try to join `#testPatrickdev`. Instead of using `#`, I use `$chr(35)` (which will in turn return the character `#`). It appends that to the value of the variable `%nick`.

Comment: mIRC used to be fun! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use mIRC's `$eval` function, eg: `$($+(#, %nick))`

Comment: there is no need to use $eval and # will be recognized as the channel where the event where triggered